# How to make tables in Rmarkdown as Word

Tags: r, html-table, r-markdown

I am trying to include a table in Rmarkdown that it looks like in Word. This is how I have the table in Word:

[image]

Is there a way that I can include this table exactly as the image in a Rmardown document?

Comment: What is your output format from rmarkdown? can you `dput()` the table data in to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a screenshot of the table from the document and use

```
 ![Caption for the picture.](/path/to/your/folder/imagename.png)
```

---

If we want to create a table from a model object use `gtsummary` or `flextable`

```
library(gtsummary)
library(flextable)
data(trial)
model <- glm(response ~ trt, trial, family = binomial) 
tbl_regression(model)
as_flextable(model)
```

---

Based on the format showed, `crosstable` would also work

```
library(crosstable)
crosstable(ggplot2::mpg, class, by = drv) %>% 
    crosstable::as_flextable()
```

[image]

Comment: And if I cannot do it this way, is there another posibility to make the table directly in the Rmardown document?

Comment: @JesúsAsdrúbalMolinaVíquez yes, there are lots of packages in R that does that i.e. kable, formattable, gt, flex_table, It depends on the input data.  As there was no input in the post i.e. only images showed it cannot be tested

Comment: The table in the i.e posted does not have an input. The porpouse is to show the process o variable creation for a linear regression model. Is there any package that could make tables without an input data?

Comment: @JesúsAsdrúbalMolinaVíquez you can use the updated code

Comment: @JesúsAsdrúbalMolinaVíquez can you test the code

Comment: Ok. I am going to try it and see how it goes

Comment: @JesúsAsdrúbalMolinaVíquez please note that some models won't work in those packages, but i think `gtsummary` is more general

Comment: Ok. I am going to be careful with that

Comment: @JesúsAsdrúbalMolinaVíquez if it works, please consider to upvote/accept solution thanks